# Send JSON data to different handlebars templates based on data object array

Tags: handlebars.js

I'm not sure if this can be done, but I have this JSON structure:

```
var data = {"obj": [
              {"user": "Fred", "age": "23", "type": "personal"},
              {"user": "Ralph", "age": "32", "type": "business"},
              {"user": "John", "age": "44", "type": "other"}
             ]
           };
```

I have 3 target areas in my HTML page where I would like to display user, and age based on the "type". I'm using handlebars to render these and have this in my ajax:

```
var source, 
template = Handlebars.compile(source), 
data;

$.each(data['obj'], function (i, o) {
    if (o['type'] === "personal") {
        source = $("#personal").html();
        $("#place1").html(template(data));
    } else if (o['type'] === "business") {
        source = $("#business").html();
        $("#place2").html(template(data));
    } else if (o['type'] === "casual") {
        source = $("#other").html();
        $("#place3").html(template(data));
    }
});
```

I was hoping to have it so that the $.each function would send each object array to the designated areas, but they end up just sending a batch to one section, then the next, and so on. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. The compiled template function, `template` in your case, takes an object as its argument so you could say:

```
$('#place1').html(template(o));
```

and then the template would use `{{user}}` and `{{age}}` to access the data; for example:

```
{{user}}'s age is {{age}}
```

If you want to change the actual template for each type then just call `Handlebars.compile` again:

```
if(o.type === 'personal') {
    template = Handlebars.compile($('#personal').html());
    $('#place1').html(template(o));
}
```

You could cache the compiled templates in an object if you wanted.

Comment: shouldn't the template be recompiled after source changes?